# split item of list at random position

Tags: python, split

My .txt file contains words (all two or three syllable words, each word on a new line in the .txt file) that are hyphenated with the use of '-'. I am looking for a way to shift the place of this '-' randomly over trials one place to the left or right. This is the code to return each word as a list of syllables:

```
for thisTrial in trials:
    wordList = thisTrial['word'].split("-")
    print wordList
```

This returns for example:

> ['ward', 'robe']
>
> ['dent', 'ist']
>
> ...

But what I would like as a result is:

> ['war', 'drobe'] or ['wardr', 'obe']
>
> ['den', 'tist'] or ['denti', 'st']
>
> ...

Any ideas on how to obtain this result?

Comment: There is exactly one hyphen in each word?

Comment: No, one or two.

Comment: Maybe you'll provide more examples of input and output? It is still not clear what you want.

Comment: In the txt file there are words containing 2 or 3 syllables. The syllables are demarcated by using hyphens. So, words contain 1 or 2 hyphens. What I want is to obtain to randomly move the hyphen(s) one place to left or right. Input: hy-dro-gen Desired outcome: one of the four following options h-ydrog-en or hyd-r-ogen or h-ydr-ogen or hyd-rog-en. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Let's assume you have following word: `hydro-g-e-n` is this output valid: `hydrog-e-n-`, or `hydrog--e-n`?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one hyphen in each word

```
from random import random

for word in ["hel-lo", "worl-d"]:
  pos = word.find("-")
  mov = 1 if random() > 0.5 else -1
  new_word = word.replace("-", "")
  split = [new_word[0:pos+mov], new_word[pos+mov:]]
  print(split)

#=> ['he', 'llo']
#=> ['world', '']
# or
#=> ['hell', 'o']
#=> ['wor', 'ld']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint   
results = [] 
for i in range(1,15):
   randomSlicePt = random.randint(1,len(word))
   results.append(word[0:randomSlicePt] + '-' + word[randomSlicePt:len(word)])


>>> results
['ward-robe', 'wardro-be', 'wardr-obe', 'war-drobe', 'ward-robe', 'war-drobe', 'wardr-obe', 'wa-rdrobe', 'wa-rdrobe', 'wardr-obe', 'ward-robe', 'wardrobe-', 'war-drobe', 'war-drobe']
```

Or you don't care about the hyphen anymore and just want to dial through some random spits of the word.

```
results = [] 
def trial(word):
     randomSlicePt = random.randint(1,len(word))
     answer = []
     answer.append(word[0:randomSlicePt])
     answer.append(word[randomSlicePt:len(word)])
     results.append(answer)

for word in wordlist:
       trial(word) 
results
```

Comment: OP asked for randomly 1 to the left or right, not all enumerations.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
import random
def test():
    word      = "ward-robe"
    delimiter = word.find('-')
    word      = word.replace('-','')
    l = [1,-1][random.getrandbits(1)]
    result = word[0:d-l],word[d-l:]
    print(result)

> test()
('war', 'drobe')

> test()
('wardr', 'obe')
```